# Recommended way to apply a filter/scope to an Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have the following association in my model:

Owner.rb

```rb
has_many :animals, through: :available_animals, source: :animal
```

I want to add a filters to `available_animals`

in an outside method:

```rb
available_animals = owner.available_animals.select{|animal| animal.available ? && animal.purchasable_at <= date_of_choice }
```

In owner.rb model

```rb
def active_price
  active_properties.where(available: true).pluck(:price).sum
end
```

I have other filters I want to apply to available animals such but I was wondering if there's a good way to consolidate this (should I be using a scope?)

Comment: Can you post the associations for the three models? Might help clarify what you're after.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you turn the query into an array (which you do by calling `select`), you can't chain any more _query_ methods. So maybe you should rewrite that `select` code to use `where` instead.